# Delay when connecting piano to the computer

Tags: audio-recording, windows, piano

I am trying to record my piano's audio on my computer without an interface. This is what I have tried:

I connect my piano to my laptop (Windows 11) using [this cable](https://www.thomann.de/intl/pro_snake_tpy2015_kpp.htm).

So one end connects to the headset input on my piano and the other end connects to the headset input on my laptop.

This works fine so far, so I can only hear the sound from the piano through my laptop. But my problem is that there is always a delay of about 1 second.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a common problem. Windows sound system is so complex that a full route through it can take an intolerable long time.

Common solutions to reduce the latency:

1. Use an external mixer which outputs to your phones the piano sound directly from the piano, mixes to it the possible reference output from the computer or another music player and directs the piano sound also to the computer for recording.
2. Use a properly designed audio workstation software for recording. Such programs generally allow low latency ASIO audio drivers. Utility program ASIO4ALL (freeware) uses normal computer audio hardware, but bypasses the normal long latency Windows sound system drivers and makes the audio workstation program able to see an ASIO4ALL as a selectable audio device.

Get ASIO4ALL from here https://www.asio4all.org

The latency will reduce to a few 10 milliseconds. It's not perfect, but it's something that you maybe can accept.

3. Use an external USB audio interface for recording instead of computer's own audio hardware. Such interfaces give often the direct monitoring option. It works as well as using an external audio mixer. They have also low latency ASIO drivers. Cheapest "plug and play, no installations needed" -type devices do not have them. Check the specs and read reviews, find local help if you do not understand the terminology.

As said, high quality external audio interfaces generally have low latency ASIO drivers, but ASIO4ALL is a workaround for those who want to use computer's own audio hardware and cannot use a hardware mixer for low latency monitoring.

Warning: Audio hardware with ASIO audio driver cannot be used at the same time by several applications. The low latency is achieved by making the internal function straightforward.

Comment: I tried it with ASIO4ALL, but unfortunately there is still a delay. During playing the piano, it takes my concentration. So I think the USP audio interface will be the better solution. Thanks for this helpful answer!

Comment: @RezaSaadati Try to shorten the recording and playback buffers. They cannot be arbitary short, but find in your system the limit where the latency is as short as possible without causing audio dropouts.

Comment: I found a good solution! 1 end of the cable is in the headset input of my piano and the other end is in the microphone input of my laptop. BUT my piano has 2 inputs for 2 headsets. So I use a real headset to hear the sound, but at the same time the audio can be recorded on my laptop. So in that case there is no latency (at least from what I hear).